# Failed to execute supplied script: 04070031 Access Denied

Tags: alfresco

I am new in the **Alfresco**, and I am developing my first project,
I have a user who is approving some requests, on approval some web scripts are going to execute.
But we are getting below error.

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Exception while invoking TaskListener: 04070032 Failed to execute the supplied script: 04070031 Access Denied. You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.
```

It's more than 2 days since I stuck on this error if anyone has an idea please help.

Comment: can you please full stacktrace of the log ? Are you performing any operation which requires admin permission(like deleting user  ?

Comment: The web scripts which are going to execute,it require admin permission.You can execute that webscript as admin.